# Validation on each class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to achieve the validation on each class.

**This is my code**

```
jQuery(function ($){
  $(".thevoornaam, .date_of_birt, .livingkid, .right, .limitSelected, .pijlers, .total_pijlers").bind("keyup change", function() {
      if ($(".thevoornaam").val().length > 1 && $('.date_of_birth').val().length == 10  && $(".livingkid").is(':checked') && $(".right").is(':checked') && $(".limitSelected:checked").val() == "1" && $(".pijlers").val() != null && $(".total_pijlers").val() != null)   {
          $("#stepbirth").removeClass("disabled");
      } 
      else if ($(".thevoornaam").val().length > 1 && $('.date_of_birth').val().length == 10  && $(".livingkid").is(':checked') && $(".right").is(':checked') && $(".limitSelected:checked").val() == "0")   {
        $("#stepbirth").removeClass("disabled");
      }
      else {
           $("#stepbirth").addClass("disabled");
      }
    });
  });
```

This is working fine, how can i this code to be work on each class element.

Thank in advance

Comment: Create an array of all the selectors and iterate it with the function you currently have

Comment: Explain it better what you're willing to do or ask.

Comment: so right now its not working for all class elements ?

Comment: Yes it is working for all class element.

Comment: May we know what is the problem then?